# InvalidOperationException causing break in Visual Studio even when handled in C# code

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, exception

In my C# application, I am catching exceptions of type `SystemException`, yet Visual Studio 2015 breaks when the exception is raised:

[image]

As you can see in the screen-capture above, I am intentionally releasing an `ISupportInitialize` lock early, before certain objects are initialized.  I am expecting the exception, and have a catch block.

Also, the exceptions I am interested in are not listed in the exception settings window; i.e. they are not checked to go into the break mode.

And although the dialog shows that "Break when this exception is thrown" is unchecked, and yet, the application still goes into break mode.


**EDIT:**

Stack trace requested by SLaks:

PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.GlyphRun.CheckInitialized()   Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.GlyphRun.ComputeInkBoundingBox()  Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.BoundsDrawingContextWalker.DrawGlyphRun(System.Windows.Media.Brush foregroundBrush, System.Windows.Media.GlyphRun glyphRun)   Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.RenderData.DrawingContextWalk(System.Windows.Media.DrawingContextWalker ctx)  Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.RenderData.GetContentBounds(System.Windows.Media.BoundsDrawingContextWalker ctx)  Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.GetHitTestBounds()    Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Visual.PrecomputeContent()    Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Visual.PrecomputeRecursive(out System.Windows.Rect bboxSubgraph)  Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Visual.PrecomputeRecursive(out System.Windows.Rect bboxSubgraph)  Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Visual.PrecomputeRecursive(out System.Windows.Rect bboxSubgraph)  Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Visual.PrecomputeRecursive(out System.Windows.Rect bboxSubgraph)  Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Visual.PrecomputeRecursive(out System.Windows.Rect bboxSubgraph)  Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Visual.PrecomputeRecursive(out System.Windows.Rect bboxSubgraph)  Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Visual.PrecomputeRecursive(out System.Windows.Rect bboxSubgraph)  Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Visual.Precompute()   Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.CompositionTarget.System.Windows.Media.ICompositionTarget.Render(bool inResize, System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE.Channel channel)    Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.Render(System.Windows.Media.ICompositionTarget resizedCompositionTarget) Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(object resizedCompositionTarget)    Unknown
    PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(object resizedCompositionTarget)    Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs)  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl()   Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(object state)  Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state)  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke()   Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue()  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled)  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(object o) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs)  Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs)   Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam)  Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]
    [Managed to Native Transition]
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame)   Unknown
    WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunDispatcher(object ignore)   Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.RunInternal(System.Windows.Window window)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run(System.Windows.Window window)  Unknown
    PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Application.Run()  Unknown
    FargoApp.exe!FargoApp.App.Main()    Unknown
    [Native to Managed Transition]
    [Managed to Native Transition]
    mscorlib.dll!System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(string assemblyFile, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, string[] args) Unknown
    Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.Utilities.dll!Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()   Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(object state)    Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx)   Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) Unknown
    mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()    Unknown

Comment: What's the stack trace?

Comment: @SLaks When I click Debug->Windows->Call Stack, it just displays [External Code] in the panel.

Comment: Disable Just My Code.

Comment: @SLaks OK, posted the stack trace as edit to question, thank you.

Comment: The stack trace tells you that it did not crash on this code at all, no sign of an EndInit() call.  Also visible from the screenshot, the currently executing statement is not highlighted.  It bombed when trying to Render, that's all internal code so nothing to look at.  Or to put it another way, the invalid EndInit() call destabilized the visual tree too much.  You caught and handled an exception that cannot be handled.

Comment: I think the exception occurs in another thread. Try using DispatcherUnhandledException in your App.xaml.cs by subscribing a handler an see if the exception is caught. Otherwise please provide a sample that can be reproduced by community. =)

Comment: @HansPassant So, the moral of the story is, if you are to start an `ISupportInitialize.BeginInit()`, you better initialize everything properly, or don't call BeginInit() at all.  Thank you.

Comment: @taquion I did what you suggested, and was able to catch the exception.  Please provide your comment as an answer so I can accept it.  Thank you so much.

Comment: @Sabuncu, done. =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not catch the exception probably because it occurs in another thread. For such scenarios you can add an event handler to **DispatcherUnhandledExceptiont** event in your App.xaml.cs, like this:

```
DispatcherUnhandledException += (sender, args) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Wild exception appeared!!!");
            };
```

This way you can be sure that exceptions thrown by your applications but not handled will trigger this handler. Mor info [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx)

Hope this helps!